# Is there any reason why Edge returns true for /^.+<\?xml/i.test('<?xml version="1.0"?><root/>')?

Tags: javascript, regex, microsoft-edge

Anyone else seeing the code https://jsfiddle.net/1rgknpwq/ respectively inserted below return true with Edge? For me with Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 it does.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><root/>';
var regex = /^.+<\?xml/i;
var test = regex.test(xml);
var result = 'Checking ' + regex + ".test('" + xml + "'): " + test;
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<section>
<h2>Test</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
</section>
```

Seems like a bug, no?

Here is an attempt to reduce it further, based on the comment:

```js
var str = '<';
var regex = /^.</i;
var test = regex.test(str);
var result = 'Checking ' + regex + ".test('" + str + "'): " + test;
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<section>
<h2>Test</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
</section>
```

For that reduced case Edge gives the right result `false`, like IE, Chrome, Firefox. Nevertheless the first code snippet gives me false for Chrome, Firefox, IE, but not with the cited Edge version.

The minimal test case to exhibit the problem with the cited Edge version is https://jsfiddle.net/vx9dz8cw/, it also checks that the first character in the input is the less than sign `<` so that there are no invisible characters before it:

```js
var xml = '<?';
var regex = /^.+<\?/i;
var test = regex.test(xml);
var result = 'Checking ' + regex + ".test('" + xml + "') with xml.charAt(0) being '" + xml.charAt(0) + "': " + test;
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<section>
<h2>Test</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
</section>
```

if we remove the question marks from the input and the regular expression pattern then the code (https://jsfiddle.net/vx9dz8cw/1/) works fine:

```js
var xml = '<';
var regex = /^.+</i;
var test = regex.test(xml);
var result = 'Checking ' + regex + ".test('" + xml + "') with xml.charAt(0) being '" + xml.charAt(0) + "': " + test;
console.log(result);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = result;
```

```html
<section>
<h2>Test</h2>
<pre id="result"></pre>
</section>
```

Comment: My guess is that the test string contains a character before the `<`. Reduce it to raw: `if ( /^.</.test('<'`)` ...This is as fundamental as it gets.

Comment: Edge 38.14393.1066.0 returns false, even in the fiddle.

Comment: If the reduced case does not show the unexpected behaviour, it's not a case and irrelevant for the question. Please try to reduce the regex and input string to something that still exhibits the behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi: It's a point of reference. Like a control case. And a response to sln's comment to boot.

Comment: Reducing the input (and the corresponding regex) to two characters, this issue seems to be limited only to certain characters as the first character. For example, any input that starts with an ASCII letter, number, or space does not test true. I haven't tested all possibilities to narrow it down to exactly which characters cause this, but it's clear right away that this isn't just an issue with XML strings or something, in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: @sln, I have reduced the test case as you suggested, that doesn't exhibit the problem.

Comment: @HuguesM., thanks for testing, it looks like a regression then it current Edge.

Comment: @Bergi, I have reduced the test input and pattern to the minimum, still looks like a bug in that cited Edge version to me.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. Yes, it clearly is a bug (If that was you title question - no, this behaviour is not permitted), you might want to report it to microsoft. My guess would be that something ignores the escaping and interprets the regex like `/^.+<?/`, with `<` being optional.

Comment: After some searching it looks as if Edge Javascript engine bugs are to be reported on GitHub so I filed https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3366. Let's see what they respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the problem as https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3366 on the Microsoft ChakraCore Javascript Engine that Edge uses and it turned out to be a already known bug with an already implemented [fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/pull/3201) that is now also included in the latest standalone release ChakraCore 1.6 of that engine and should therefore make its way into a future Edge release.